# How to correctly set groups in TradeCaptureReport?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I'm trying to set the groups correctly for the TradeCaptureReport from DTO. The first side is always the Buyer and the second is the Seller.

I have such an example, but it is badly done, could someone help how to set it up correctly?

```
 public static TradeCaptureReport mapToTrade(TradeMessageDTO tradeMessageDTO) {
        final TradeCaptureReport tradeCaptureReport = new TradeCaptureReport();
        tradeCaptureReport.setField(new LastPx(tradeMessageDTO.getLastPx()));
        tradeCaptureReport.setField(new LastQty(tradeMessageDTO.getLastQty()));
        tradeCaptureReport.setField(new Symbol(tradeMessageDTO.getSymbol()));
        tradeCaptureReport.setField(new TransactTime(LocalDateTime.now()));
        tradeCaptureReport.setField(new TradeDate(tradeMessageDTO.getTradeDate()));
        tradeCaptureReport.setField(new TradeReportTransType(tradeMessageDTO.getTradeReportTransType()));
        tradeCaptureReport.setField(new PreviouslyReported(getPreviouslyReported(tradeMessageDTO)));
        tradeCaptureReport.setField(new TradeReportID(tradeMessageDTO.getTradeReportID()));
        tradeCaptureReport.setField(new TrdType(tradeMessageDTO.getTrdType()));
        tradeCaptureReport.setField(new NoSides(tradeMessageDTO.getNoSides()));

        Group group1 = new Group(1, NoSides.FIELD);                                 // BUY SIDE
        group1.setField(new Side(tradeMessageDTO.getBuyerSide().getSide()));
        group1.setField(new OrderID(tradeMessageDTO.getBuyerSide().getOrderID()));
        group1.setField(new NoPartyIDs(tradeMessageDTO.getBuyerSide().getNoPartyIDs()));
        group1.setField(new PartyID(tradeMessageDTO.getBuyerSide().getPartyID()));
        group1.setField(new PartyIDSource(tradeMessageDTO.getBuyerSide().getPartyIDSource()));
        group1.setField(new PartyRole(tradeMessageDTO.getBuyerSide().getPartyRole()));
        group1.setField(new Account(tradeMessageDTO.getBuyerSide().getAccount()));
        group1.setField(new TradingSessionID(tradeMessageDTO.getBuyerSide().getTradingSessionID()));

        Group group2 = new Group(2, NoSides.FIELD);                                 // SELL SIDE
        group2.setField(new Side(tradeMessageDTO.getSellerSide().getSide()));
        group2.setField(new OrderID(tradeMessageDTO.getSellerSide().getOrderID()));
        group2.setField(new NoPartyIDs(tradeMessageDTO.getSellerSide().getNoPartyIDs()));
        group2.setField(new PartyID(tradeMessageDTO.getSellerSide().getPartyID()));
        group2.setField(new PartyIDSource(tradeMessageDTO.getSellerSide().getPartyIDSource()));
        group2.setField(new PartyRole(tradeMessageDTO.getSellerSide().getPartyRole()));
        group2.setField(new Account(tradeMessageDTO.getSellerSide().getAccount()));
        group2.setField(new TradingSessionID(tradeMessageDTO.getSellerSide().getTradingSessionID()));

        tradeCaptureReport.addGroup(group1);
        tradeCaptureReport.addGroup(group2);

        return tradeCaptureReport;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the groups do not line up correctly, I get a duplicate tag 1 and tag 2 which I have not added anywhere at all, Have any of you faced a similar problem? Regards :)

Comment: Maybe it would also be beneficial if you posted the error message you are getting.

Comment: I consider the @ChristophJohn 's answer the most appropriated way to solve it. The problem on your code is: the Group constructor receives two parameters:  (1) the tag which indicates the number of group elements inside the repeating group and (2) the tag which represents the first tag inside the group. The code is informing wrong values for the first parameter new Group (1.   new Group (2

Answer (score 1):

Check this page for a simple example:

https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/repeating_groups.html

Specific to your code I'd suggest the following:

- Do not set the `NoSides` field by yourself. It will be done implicitly by QFJ when you add the group to the message.
- Do not create a general `Group` but use `TradeCaptureReport.NoSides()`.
- Do not set contents of the `Party` group inside the `NoSides` group field by field but use the specific group `TradeCaptureReport.NoSides.NoPartyIDs()`.