# How to correctly set NoSides and Side in TradeCaptureReport?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

I am using the latest version of Quickfix to simulate sending a TradeCaptureReport. To do that, I set the values of the mandatory component noSides and Sides. When I do that, I get an error saying

> ......22458=Incorrect NumInGroup count for repeating group, field=....

Unfortunately, the answer to this question : [How to correctly set groups in TradeCaptureReport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68622843/how-to-correctly-set-groups-in-tradecapturereport)
and the examples within the library are made in 4.4 and so do not apply in my case.

```
TradeCaptureReport tradeCaptureReport = new TradeCaptureReport();
Instrument instrument = new Instrument();
instrument.set(new Symbol("XXX"));//55
instrument.set(new SecurityID("XXXXXX")); //48

TrdCapRptSideGrp trdCapRptSideGrp =new TrdCapRptSideGrp();
 // Create and add the NoSides group with the individual sides of the trade
NoSides noSides = new NoSides();
noSides.setValue(NoSides.ONE_SIDE);
trdCapRptSideGrp.set(noSides);
trdCapRptSideGrp.setField(new Side(Side.BUY));
tradeCaptureReport.set(new LastPx(123456));
tradeCaptureReport.set(new LastQty(1234));
tradeCaptureReport.set(new SettlDate("20231018"));
tradeCaptureReport.set(instrument);
tradeCaptureReport.set(trdCapRptSideGrp);
```

Comment: When i try to set the values of NoSides and Side i get this error : .....458=Tag not defined for this message type, field=....

Comment: Why do the answers not apply to your case? Just replace the FIX4.4 classes with the 5.0 ones. And importantly: DO NOT SET the NoSides field by yourself.